# Android: Размытый Vector на android 4.4

Tags: java, android, изображения, vector

Всем привет!

У меня появилась проблема:

Есть `TextView` и хочу у него фон сделать `VectorDrawable`'ом делаю `vector.xml`

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="114.0"
    android:viewportWidth="494.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M12,86.61L2.19,76.51L12,67.18L12,8C12,3.58 15.59,0 20.01,0L483.99,0C488.42,0 492,3.58 492,8L492,102C492,106.42 488.41,110 483.99,110L20.01,110C15.58,110 12,106.42 12,102L12,86.61Z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

и этот вектор на `android 4.4` имеет размытые края (не четкие), но на `android 5.0+` все хорошо смотрится (как нужно).

Помогите решить задачу с `android 4.4`

Comment: мне кажется тут больше 9.patch подойдет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету из комментария нашел сайт с `9.patch`

[собственно сайт](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

затем взял готовый svg файл, загрузил , настроил поля растяжений на разные экраны, скачал .png файлы, и использовал в проекте, это решило вопрос как с размытостью на версиях < 5.0 и дало эффект растяжения только нужных частей background.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в векторе определено стандартное разрешение height="24dp" и width="24dp".
Увеличте это значение и проблема будет решена.